# Updating props for React Native Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, react-native

I am trying to update my React Native view from native Android, by updating properties. Following the [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/integration-with-android-fragment#step-4-add-a-react-native-fragment-to-the-framelayout), I can pass properties from native Android (Kotlin) to a React Native view for initial render. However, I don't see a way to update properties on user action.

I see it's possible if using a [react root view](https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-android), but not with ReactFragments.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working with a similar method to iOS. I'm using Kotlin and I have a base react fragment class that exposes the ReactRootView for a fragment when it's created and then when I need to update props I just find that fragment and set its app properties like so:

```kotlin
val fm = supportFragmentManager
val searchFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_SEARCH_FRAGMENT_REACT) as SearchFragmentReact?
searchFragment?.reactRootView?.appProperties = props
```

Not sure if this is the correct or best way but it worked for me.